Prioritize specific nodes in slurm job submission
Is there a way to prioritize certain nodes over others in a job submission without admin privileges?
I know about the --nodelist, --constraint or --exclude directives, but if set, the job runs only if the nodes specified are free and does not run on the others.
More specifically, I have 3 nodes with three different kinds of GPUs (fast, medium, slow) that have a feature (A100, V100, the last one has no feature to it). I want Slurm to schedule the job to run on one of the three nodes, with a decreasing preference from the fast to the slow GPU node.
Is there a way to do this in the Slurm batch job submission script?
